# Qt5 summer hour

Tags: qt, qdatetime

I create a QDateTime :

> QDateTime(QDate(1970,01,01), QTime(0,0,0,0))

and when we are in summer hour I would create

> QDateTime(QDate(1970,01,01), QTime(01,0,0,0))

How know if we are in summer hour or winter hour ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google search and you can read all about the answer here: -
http://www.zetcode.com/gui/qt4/datetime/

Just search for 'daylight saving' in the article.